# is using same conda env in multiple nodes can affect execution speed?

Tags: python, conda

I am using anaconda as my package manager
And my nodes are intergrated with NAS, which allows each node to use same env without modifications.
however, when I use multiple nodes with one conda env, python execution almost stops.

ex) ssh node1, python train.py produces logs, which indicates training is going well.
while training in node1, ssh node2, python train.py does not produces log

What could be the problem?

Comment: Via Snakemake, I've deployed thousands of *independent* jobs simultaneously using the same environment and never had issues. Seems like you need to give more details about the nature of the jobs.

Comment: @merv sorry for lack of informations. but I am not sure what details will be required to solve this. l will just add more informations what I assume to be needed, since I am not a network expert..  
first. each nodes are intergrated with NAS and infiniband/lustre, so if I change node1 ~/hello.py, node2 ~/hello.py will be changed. Also, same conda env(in example, env_1) is accessible by each node. If I run hello.py in node1~2 with env_1, It seems to be working(since it produces log). however 3 or more node uses same env_1 at the same time, it lags, and does not produce logs.

Comment: @merv I solved this problem with cloning conda env(env_1 -> env_1, 2,3...) and using each node different conda env(technically identical envs), but I am not sure why.